# My MainActivity starts two intents...

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm starting my App with the MainActivity. In this MainActivity i check if the app is starting the first time.. If the app starts the first time, it should start the WelcomeActivity. If the app isn't started the first time it should start the LoginActivity..

This is the code of my MainActivity

```
    // First start - show welcome activity
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean firstStart = sp.getBoolean("configured", false);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "First:" + String.valueOf(firstStart));
    if (!firstStart) {
        // starts the WelcomeActivity
        Log.d("MainActivity", "starting WelcomeActivity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // account protected?
    //long accountId = sp.getLong("accountId", 0);
    long accountId = 0;
    if (accountId == 0 || !UserManagement.checkAccountProtected(accountId, this)) {
        // Show Login
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Now.. my Problem is that i see the WelcomeActivity and in the next moment the LoginActivity.. Can anybody tell my why?

SORRY for my english... ;)

PS: In the two other activities i show only some input fields..

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set cofigured after first launch to true as boolean value
just like this :

EDIT

```
  // First start - show welcome activity   
    boolean firstStart = sp.getBoolean("configured", false);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "First:" + String.valueOf(firstStart));
    if (!firstStart) {
        // starts the WelcomeActivity
        Log.d("MainActivity", "starting WelcomeActivity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }else {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("configured",true).apply();   
    // account protected?
    //long accountId = sp.getLong("accountId", 0);
    long accountId = 0;
    if (accountId == 0 || !UserManagement.checkAccountProtected(accountId, this)) {
        // Show Login
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work.. I'm setting the configured also in the welcome activity but it skips my activity.. i see in my logs: "starting welcomeActivity" and directly after that: "starting LoginActivity"

Answer (score 0):

To make it all works, you need not only check `configured` but also **SET** it. So once your `WelcomeActivity` is done, if should set `configured` so next time your app is launched, Welcome can be skipped

Comment: I do this in my WelcomeActivity - sorry. But when i'm installing the app completely new to my device its skips the welcome activity and shows my the LoginActivity

Comment: `completely new` means there's no app data on the device. So it is all working fine

Comment: Well i creating new virtual devices with no app data and it doesn't working.. :/